# How to Push data dynamically from firebase to bar graph in angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, chart.js, ng2-charts

Html File :

```
<div>
<div class = "container" >
  <div style="display: block" >
    <canvas baseChart 
    [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
              (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">

    </canvas>
  </div>
```

[image: output with console]I want to show count of how many type of call(incoming,missed,outgoing)is there,data on graph, problem is it is not pushing in barChartData[] array. Data is stored in firestore, I'm able to retrieve it,also it's showing in console. If I pass static data it's coming perfect.While dynamic is not coming. Here they return number of type of calls being made. 
If anyone has some idea about this, do help please.
Thank you

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';

export interface Post {
  callType: string;
  ...
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-screen2',
  templateUrl: './screen2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./screen2.component.scss'],
})

export class Screen2Component implements OnInit {
postsCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
posts: Observable<Post[]>;

 public barChartOptions: any = {
   scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
  };

  public barChartLabels  = [ "incoming" , "missed" , "outgoing"];
  public barChartType  = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  inco: any ;
  miss: any ;
  outg: any ;
    ab: any;
    bc: any;

  public barChartData: any[] = [
  {data: [], label: 'calls'}
];
isDataAvailable: boolean = false;

public chartClicked(e: any): void {
  console.log(e);
}

public chartHovered(e: any): void {
  console.log(e);
}
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}
  ngOnInit() {

    let i;
    this.postsCol = this.db.collection<Post>('ana', ref => ref.orderBy('callType'));
    this.postsCol.valueChanges().subscribe(daa => {

for(i=0; i <= daa.length; i++) {
           this.ab = (daa[i].callType);
           if(this.ab == 'INCOMING'){
             this.inco = this.ab;
             console.log(this.inco)
          }
           if(this.ab == 'OUTGOING'){
             this.outg = this.ab
             console.log(this.outg)
           }
           if(this.ab == 'MISSED'){
            this.miss = this.ab
            console.log(this.miss)
       }

this.barChartData = [
            { data: [this.inco, this.miss, this.outg], label: 'calls'}
          ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a `config` variable like this:

```
public config = {
    type: 'bar',
    legend: true,
    data: {
      labels: [ "incoming" , "missed" , "outgoing"],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'calls',
        data: []
      }]
    }
  }
```

In your `html` file, put this:

```
<div style="display: block">
   <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block"></canvas>
</div>
```

In the `ngOnInit()` function do this (variables `ctx` and `myBarChart` must be defined earlier):

```
this.ctx = document.getElementById('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement
this.myBarChart = new Chart(this.ctx.getContext('2d'), this.config)
```

When you want to update the data, you can do it this way:

```
this.myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data = your_firebase_data;
this.myBarChart.update()
```

Cheers

Comment: Hey thank you, but I haven't posted my HTML file, have updated it.

Comment: Yes, I used to follow the same tactic as you. But it was not convenient when trying to update a chart on the fly. Try the approach I described and you will get what you want.

Comment: Attempting to configure '_chartjs' with descriptor '[object Object]' on object 'INCOMING' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object . Getting this error

Comment: `import { Chart } from 'chart.js';` Did you import `Chart`?

Comment: Yes, I think data is not being pushed correctly. Check this --this.myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data = this.inco;

Comment: It should be like this `this.myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data = [this.inco, this.missed, this.outgoing]`

Comment: @Oretis Zekai Hey,I want to show dynamic labels on graph. Can you please help me out. Thank You.

Comment: `this.myBarChart.data.labels = my_new_labels` and then `this.myBarChart.update()`. It should work